# In java, is the Stream.Builder thread safe?

Tags: java, stream

Can the add method of the Stream.Builder be called by multiple threads at the same time?

Comment: The documentation doesn't say so, and the default presumption is that it is not thread-safe.

Comment: Stream.Builder builds a stream. Stream operates on Collections. If the collections is not thread safe then stream wont be thread safe either. So I would assume it is not thread safe.

Answer (score -2):

StreamBuilder is not thread-safe implementation. I would recommend use StreamBuffer instead of StreamBuilder in multi thread implementation.

Comment: Do you have any documentation or evidence to support your statement that it is not thread safe?

Comment: I think you're confusing it with  `StringBuilder`.